# document.getElementById as jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this pattern being used in some code...

```
currency = $(document.getElementById('currency'));
```

Which is expect is functionally equivalent to...

```
currency = $('#currency');
```

I am guessing the idea is to make the selector faster, as it does not need to parse the selection string... but does it really make a discernible difference? Is there something else at play I have not considered?

Why would someone use this kind of pattern?

Comment: In the end, `getElementById` will be called either way. This looks to me a little bit like a micro optimization... Let's not even get into readability :P

Comment: [This comparison](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44) actually hints that there is an improvement with your first example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, when parsing the selector string passed, jQuery automatically detects that you passed an `id` selector and calls `document.getElementById` for you.

So, when you're fetching the element yourself prior the call to jQuery, you're only saving the selector parsing portion, but that's negligible for most use cases.

See [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L74)

Answer (score 2):

No sense to use first sintax -- both do the same ( at second part you skip parsing for jq-query )  -- also jq can cache requests -- so just right $('#..') and keep your code clean
[image]
http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-as-jquery-selector

Comment: Hey, jsperf is back up - great stuff!

Comment: That's an interesting test -- testing the case where it doesn't match anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder   that was problem description -- we just test selection an element -- can you propose some improvement? I'll be very grateful

Comment: with non-empty selector: http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-as-jquery-selector/2

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk: I don't see anything about the element not existing in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw this pattern being used in some code...
>
> currency = $(document.getElementById('currency'));
>
> Which is expect is functionally equivalent to...
>
> currency = $('#currency');

**Now**, yes. It didn't used to be, back when IE6 and IE7 were still on the scene. The `getElementById` in IE7 and earlier was broken and would return elements with a matching `name` as well as a matching `id`. jQuery (1.x) has intelligence built into it to deal with broken old browsers. Thankfully, Microsoft fixed this in IE8.

> I am guessing the idea is to make the selector faster, as it does not need to parse the selection string... but does it really make a discernible difference?

It probably makes an actual difference, but not in a way that translates to anything perceptible in the real world. The only way to know for sure is to [test it](http://jsperf.com) on a DOM that's representative of the ones you want to know the answer for, and on the browsers that you want to know the answer for. *(JSPerf seems to be having issues at the moment, though.)*

[Here's a test](http://jsperf.com/gbid-plus-jquery-vs-jquery) that *doesn't* use a representative DOM suggesting a significant percentage difference:

[image]

...but again, in real world terms unless you're doing this millions of times in a loop, it's not going to matter. Also note that what's being tested is so fast that error margins are likely to be large.

Comment: I think that test is not quite my case. In my case, after selecting with `getElementById` it is passed to jQuery wrapper - in the test, the jQuery version alone has overhead of creating jQuery instance.

Comment: @BillyMoon: Gah, missed that out. :-) But you get the idea.

Comment: interesting about IE6/7, so this pattern basically un-does the main purpose of jQuery (to smooth out browser inconsistency) as it will sometimes (in old browsers where dom element has name attr same as another's id) select the wrong element, whereas jQuery version will always select the correct element. Is that right?

Comment: @BillyMoon: Yup. For a negligible benefit. At the cost of readability and verbosity. (At the very least they could have defined `$.id()` or some such to make it more readable. :-) ) (BTW, updated the test.)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document.getElementById('currency'));` is less readable and in the end there will be `getElementById` called anyway. You will not see it's effect in most cases (element is cached and will be called only once).

Answer (score -1):

It uses `document.querySelector()` if is supported, and if not uses `document.getElementById()`
In my opinion, for non-jquery purpopses, `document.querySelector()` is better (for me)

```
 document.querySelector("#id .class > tag.nested");
```